# Linear regression for rank variable(DV) vs binary variables?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, binary-data

Im triyng to find the influence(relevance) of three binary variables(1/0) on my dependent variable that is a 1-10 scale.

Is linear regression the best type of regression for this kind of analysis?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for ordered logistic regression (though it goes by other names depending on the field), which will allow you to regress your ordered DV onto your 3 IVs while maintaining the scales prescribed order. Similarly, you could try multinomial logistic regression, which does not presuppose a particular (e.g., the data imply a 2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 order to the scale as opposed to 1-10). However, this will result in less power.

See the links below for more information.

[https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Logit.pdf](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eotorres/Logit.pdf)

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/